# git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories - Mistakes in '/usr/share/nano/git.nanorc'

Tags: git

So I'm trying to push an initial commit in IntelliJ from master to origin, I used

```
git push
```

And got this:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. 
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again. 
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

If I'm not wrong, this is supposing caused by the read.md already in the repo, so I tried to pull

```
git pull
```

and got this:

```
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

So I looked around, it's because of unrelated histories, and then I saw someone said to use this comment:

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

And all that does is bring up whatever this is:

[image]

I actually have no idea what this does, I'm pretty new to git. I tried messing around with it but ended up needed to abort my merge every time, can anyone help me out? Thanks for your time

Comment: The _simplest_ thing to do would be to set aside your work folder and start over by cloning the remote repo down to your computer.

Comment: I've tried that, however, trying to start a new IntelliJ project in the same folder as the cloned repo overrides everything inside the folder, so I couldn't do anything in it

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. I'm not suggesting that clone into the same folder or that you start anything new. I'm just talking about getting yourself a working repo that matches the remote repo.